# Solve linear equations over the integers

Tags: code-golf, math

All variables in this question are integer valued.

## Input

4 integers w, x, y, z. They can be positive or negative and will be less than 1048576 in absolute value.

## Output

The general solution to the equation.

\$ aw+bx+cy+dz = 0 \$.

The variables \$a, b, c, d\$ must all be integer values.

## Output format

Your output should consist of three tuples each with four parts, one for each of the values a, b, c, d. Let me explain by example:

```
Input: -118, 989, 918, -512

Mathematical answer:
        b = 2 n_0 
        c = 9 n_0 + 256 n_1 + 81 a
        d = 20 n_0 + 459 n_1 + 145 a
```

Explanation:  `n_0` and `n_1` are integers that you can set to anything you like. The solution says: `a` can also be set to any integer value, `b` must be twice whatever you set `n_0` to.
This means that `a` can be set to any integer, `c` can now be calculated in terms of three variables we have already set and so can `d`.

The format of your output should be 3 tuples (#,#,#,#), (#,#,#,#), (#,#,#,#). We can assume three free integer variables n0, n1 and n2 and so  (a,b,c,d) = (#,#,#,#)n0 + (#,#,#,#)n1 + (#,#,#,#)n2.  In the example above the output would therefore be:

```
Output: (0, 2, 9, 20), (0, 0, 256, 459), (1, 0, 81, 145)
```

## Examples

Example one:

```
 Input: -6, 3, 7, 8

 Mathematical answer: 
          c = 2a + 3b + 8n
          d = -a - 3b - 7n 
          n is any integer

 Output: (1, 0, 2, -1), (0, 1, 3, -3), (0, 0, 8, -7)
```

Example two:

```
Input: -116, 60, 897, 578

Mathematical answer: 
        c = 578 n + 158 a + 576 b
        d = -897 n - 245 a - 894 b 
        n is any integer

Output: (1, 0, 158, -245), (0, 1, 576, -894), (0, 0, 578, -897)
```

Example three:

```
Input: 159, -736, -845, -96

Output: (1, 0, 27, -236), (0, 1, 64, -571), (0, 0, 96, -845)
```

## Discussion

To understand this challenge further it is worth looking at this possible general solution which does **not** work `[(z, 0, 0, -w), (0, z, 0, -x), (0, 0, z, -y)]`.  The problem with this is that there are solutions to the problem instances above which are not the sum of any integer multiples of those tuples. For example: take input -6, 3, 7, 8 from Example 1.  The proposed solution would give the tuples:

```
(8, 0, 0, 6), (0, 8, 0, -3), (0, 0, 8, -7)
```

Why doesn't this work?

There is a solution for this instance with a = 1, b = 1, c = 13, d = -11 because `-6+3+7*13-11*8 = 0`. However there are no integers n_0, n_1, n_2 to make `n_0 * (8, 0, 0, 6) + n_1 * (0, 8, 0, -3) + n_2 * (0, 0, 8, -7) = (1, 1, 13, -11)` .

Comment: I do not think this challenge is a duplicate. It's a similar task, but the ways you'd do it are completely different. I don't necessarily think it's an _interesting_ challenge, but that shouldn't factor into whether or not it's a dupe of something totally different.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate. I am excited to see the answers!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 182 bytes

```python
def E(a,b):
 if b:x,y,d=E(b,a%b);return y,x-a/b*y,d
 return 1,0,a
def f(a,b,c,d):x,y,g=E(a,b);z,w,h=E(c,d);j=E(g,h)[2];return(b/g,-a/g,0,0),(0,0,d/h,-c/h),(-x*h/j,-y*h/j,z*g/j,w*g/j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLLbsJADLzvV1iqKnapVyTQvIjSG19R9ZAHJHBIEaLK4@fT8RIBFy6OPWNPvNach2vz266nN7K@HzMlcYIgmQ38tQIcMm2YIqZYuSbUoYcqARREAvoBZmy0AWPjzwAxCdVisVB5Tx9UDAjliFB1lJGnasS6rHTOhVHNXJRcmXs/oNZXj5mmXSsgKJE5jdM8VnNjFJiMdLM6mXajXIPV9a3S@ao2oqoLJIOj5kZdrhojv9AVEvnN6yGf7Bf10iKI20Tb3rsppSQt2uYPavBe/sRJjTIgCLYFN3r1rOTWsOWd6WZGzjlV@wPt3Nm2io4HKrY9D1xlO11w/l6Y9LK//l1aGrjHMsUSnKIZ89njXInCQRRY7u3G6@wmmY7ccYNCmPSERG77vf6ZVeXlLG@EkGdYIzJewG5ZxjWWeDLbwX3GJdbmTqKZzpdje9UH7Qwm/hJ7ibuMUXcu5A1HHD9DYjU4TYwGnz0x4jdnN@c2mM2Y6R8)

Yes, it is possible to solve it without fancy built-ins. And this gives relatively good results for a non-LLL one.

#### How it works

I derived a closed-form solution in the following steps: (I flipped the roles of \$a,b,c,d\$ and \$w,x,y,z\$ because it looked much more natural to me. So \$a,b,c,d\$ are coefficients and \$w,x,y,z\$ are unknowns here.)

$$
ax+by+cz+dw = 0
$$

If we define \$g=\gcd(a,b)\$ and \$h=\gcd(c,d)\$, the following substitutions can be done without loss of generality: (\$u,v\$ are temporary integer variables)

$$
ax+by = gu\\
cz+dw = hv
$$

which results in a system of two heterogeneous and one homogeneous 2-variable linear Diophantine equations:

$$
ax+by = gu \\
cz+dw = hv \\
gu + hv = 0
$$

Then we can apply the textbook procedure:

$$
u = \frac{h}{j}n_3, \; v = \frac{-g}{j}n_3 \quad \text{where} \; j = \gcd(g,h)
$$

If we let \$(x_0,y_0)\$ be a "special" solution to \$ax+by=g\$ and similarly \$(z_0,w_0)\$, then the solutions are

$$
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{b}{g}n_1 + \frac{-x_0h}{j}n_3 \\
y &= \frac{-a}{g}n_1 + \frac{-y_0h}{j}n_3 \\
z &= \frac{d}{h}n_2 + \frac{z_0g}{j}n_3 \\
w &= \frac{-c}{h}n_2 + \frac{w_0g}{j}n_3
\end{align}
$$

The special solutions can be found via Extended Euclidean algorithm. Special mention goes to [this deceptively short and yet correct implementation of EGCD](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/2168/files#diff-8b8a26ba997d624245be0a39f6a11a0faa0580739d04e058cab8a83a44e25833R231), once added to sympy but removed later:

```python
def extended_euclid(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return (1, 0, a)

    x0, y0, d = extended_euclid(b, a%b)
    x, y = y0, x0 - (a//b) * y0

    return x, y, d
```

Comment: This is really great!

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 39 bytes

Still a built-in.

`HermiteDecomposition` gives the [Hermite normal form](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteNormalForm.html) decomposition of an integer matrix.

```
HermiteDecomposition[List/@#][[1,2;;]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxCoMwFEV/5UHAKcE@bTRBWhw6dOjQPWQQiTRDTNFskm9PX10u95zLDVP6uDAlP09lgVt5ui345B5ujuEbd598XM3L76kemTUGeTMM1lblvfk1GQbiDoth1kIF9QjHIRAVB600xb8JiU3mcIiOQ8uh56BORCTRXQg1OdmfFiXdRN/SJNRVUuou5/ID)

---

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), without build-in, 118 bytes

Based on Algorithm 2.4.10 in *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory* by Henri Cohen.

The output is sometimes extremely large. You can reduce them with the build-in `LatticeReduce`.

```
(a=#[[1]];U=IdentityMatrix@4;Do[{d,u}=ExtendedGCD[a,b=#[[j]]];U[[{1,j}]]={u,{-b,a}/d}.U[[{1,j}]];a=d,{j,2,4}];Rest@U)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVDLasMwELznK5YYQgurpEr8rFExNKUUUiiBnIQOSqQQG@JCuoYUoW93ZefQ/kAvw84Mwwx71nSyZ031QfdHEP2dFpGUXKlyJ96Mbamm73dNl/paxeX6UzqDnRcvV7Ktseb1eS017odIo4aMlI5j45USrkPH9qj9wvj5r15qYdA1uMTYq3Jrv6ja3c/6j0vdkoyAPcFRRkrBDBYVOMc4zxGKvAgwXCzhS4/gWIqwQsgQ8pFyHoT0IdAiaEk2qjwJMZatgsXyOAlYpN5Pbl3TrTXdwZpHmKrJn/qNpvAMe3PlOOY/1/Q/)

Comment: If HermiteDecomposition is computing the Hermite normal form of a matrix, how are you converting a single tuple into a suitable matrix? I guess the magic is in `List/@#][[1,2;;]]` but I don't understand it.

Comment: @Anush `List/@#` converts the input to a matrix with a single column. `HermiteDecomposition` decomposes the input into a unimodular matrix (i.e., matrix with determinant ±1) and an upper-triangular matrix (i.e., the Hermite normal form). Only the last three rows of the unimodular matrix is needed (`[[1,2;;]]`).

Comment: Thank you for the first non built in solution!

Answer (score 2):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), 92 bytes

```c
def f(x,y,z,w):
 for v in'abcd':var(v,domain=ZZ)
 return solve([a*x+b*y+c*z+d*w==0],a,b,c,d)
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVjcsOgyAUBfd8xd0JeElqm7Zqwo9IWKBIYtJCQyk-vr54FpNZzbGzA0c33PHAlfUEXIiQYfGVGSdb9dlEmtGGt1m8HAZGIM7pFz18wyvPVBm-1SPf64kfteWrlBeNBkec0DJCzlgqMVBKPBBuCE-EViMo0TQtQtd2BaeJe3PVuvyXfeLiE3WUJ8b-HfUspw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: Thank you for the first answer! Even if it is a boring built-in :). The coefficients are strangely large though.

Comment: The output format is not right

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 21 bytes

Another boring built-in answer.

> matkerint(x,{flag=0}): LLL-reduced Z-basis of the kernel of the matrix x with integral entries. flag is deprecated, and may be set to 0 or 1 for backward compatibility.

```
a->matkerint(Mat(a))~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYs7CgMxDESvIraywYIoG/@K7A1ygsWFimxY8kEsbtLk6o7sZph5TxI@dnxI2@DaGJc31@f92D/V3LgatvbXWOT1NQy4gAzDMPUxwdYPHKwrEiUHOWWN3tDTuajA4GB2EB2kMYkUhJPOrMzHQcnrG8ZZFaaL18yhFNv@)

Comment: What is the ~ at the end for? Also, could you explain matkerint a little please. It looks like it should take a matrix as input but seems to be taking just a single tuple.

Comment: @Anush `Mat` converts the input into a matrix.

`matkerint` outputs a matrix whose columns are the \$\mathbb{Z}\$-basis of the kernel of the input matrix.

The `~` at the end takes the transpose of the matrix, so the columns become rows. I'm not sure if it is needed.